# mvn appengine:deploy system property for configuration

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

we are using **mvn appengine:deploy** to test and deploy our application on appengine. As this is spring-boot based application and we would like to externalize property for env, we would like to use -Dspring.profiles.active=dev but looks like mvn appengine:deploy does not honor system property specified. also, mvn -DskipTests=true appengine:deploy does not skip tests.

Answer (score 3):

For this, we would have to pass the variable via maven properties/profiles.

a. For honouring -Dspring.profiles.active=dev,

1. Go to your application.properties and add `spring.profiles.active=@spring.profiles.active@`
2. Deploy app using `mvn appengine:deploy -Dspring.profiles.active=dev`

b. For honouring -DskipTests=true,

1. In your pom.xml, create profile that sets property to skip unit test.

   [image]
2. Run `mvn appengine:deploy -Prun-test`

Comment: Thanks @Lucas, glad it helped :)